# Set user to group when created

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views

I have created a form where user can create their own group, everything work except that the group is not set to the user, so it is worthless.

This is my views.py :

```
@login_required
def creategroup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
            groupcreate = Group()
            groupcreate.user = request.user
            groupcreate.name = request.POST['name']
            groupcreate.save()
```

I have set user, but it does not take the value

Comment: Could you also share your models.py for the Group model?

Comment: Hello the group is using the models from django.auth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if you are using the django.contrib.auth Group model:

```
# a name is required!
new_group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name="the group name")
# then you can add the user
new_group.user_set.add(request.user)
```

This is because, if you look on the [models](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L315), Group does NOT have a user field. Instead it is the User model that has a m2m with Groups (via the PermissionsMixin)